# Using Right Tag (class, div, span, table, etc.) Using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I have started using the `rvest` package and have encountered some consistent problems, namely exactly how to refer to the HTML code.

For example, the below code returns a null character (ultimately want 0.74). Basically the only thing I can get to return is using "div" as the node, which just returns all text. "tr.total-return", "total-return", "div.sal-trailing-return__middle" all returned null too.

```
a=read_html(https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/hcyix/performance)
b=html_nodes(a, "td")
```

[image]

Comment: When I go to that URL, I don't see any data. Do you have to be logged in to access the site?

Comment: Fat thumbed it when copying to overflow, should be correct now

Comment: There are no `<td>` tags in the source of the document (which is different than what you see in the "elements" tab -- check out the "sources" tab for what rvest can see). Those are created after load via javascript. rvest cannot run javascript for you. If you want to interact with webpages that require javascript you'll need something like `RSelenium`.

Comment: data comes from this endpoint `https://api-global.morningstar.com/sal-service/v1/fund/trailingReturn/v2/F00000Q1AI/data?locale=en&duration=daily&currency=&languageId=en&locale=en&clientId=MDC&benchmarkId=category&component=sal-components-mip-trailing-return&version=3.31.0` - you may need to check T&C.  The path within the json returned is then object►totalReturnNAV►0 though that index in R will be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page loads dynamically. You thus need to use `RSelenium`, and not just `rvest`.

This code works for me to obtain the data point of `0.74`.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)

url<- "https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/hcyix/performance"

# RSelenium with Firefox
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(4)

# get the page source
web <- remDr$getPageSource()
web <- xml2::read_html(web[[1]])

b <- html_node(web, ".total-return > td:nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  trimws()

# close RSelenium
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I will have to read up on that documentation!